# Apps updated, now I get an unknown lock screen with ads

Tags: applications, updates, malware, ads

After finally doing a bunch of updates, suddenly every now and then some random lock screen with ads showed.

[image: Lock screen with friggin' ads]

Which app is causing this?

Comment: Agreed, as long as no one marks this one as a duplicate.. The above one points to ES Explorer being the culprit, and is older. This is a (slightly) newer phenomenon.